# What is the correct behaviour when I see a question that would be more appropriate for another site

Tags: discussion, flags, scope

What should I do whenever I see a question that would be more appropriate for another site? I have usually left a comment that this would be more appropriate for site X, but I received a comment `"@juhist, please don't ask people to cross post on other Stack Exchange sites. "Flag...`

...and I can't view the rest of the comment as the question on which the comment was left has now been deleted by its author (it was a question about database usage and the same person asked the question again on https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

So, what should I do? Should I flag the post somehow? If so, how?

Comment: See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: On http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235523/ instead of "You should consider asking this same question at superuser.com" you should flag > closed another reason > off topic > belongs on other site > super user - instead of the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, my feeling was that the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it was clearly a database question and not a programming question. The new question is here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96085/pgadmin-iii-number-of-lines-returned-during-insertion ...so perhaps somebody can comment if my feeling was correct.

Comment: Just because someone reposted it doesn't mean that it is on topic or a good question on the other site. Some sites can take a bit to get around to closing or voting on a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions which will guide your behavior:

1. Is it a good question?

   If not, simply close (or flag to close), downvote, edit as appropriate.
2. Is it on-topic on SO?

   If yes, leave it here.
3. Are you sure it's on-topic on $other_site and a good question there?
   Did you check their help-center to verify your gut-feeling and/or are you a user of that site too?

   If yes, vote to migrate. If there is no option to migrate to that site, use an "other"-flag.
4. As it's off-topic and there's no site it's a good on-topic question, simply close as off-topic.

As you are below 3K reputation, substitute flagging for closure where I advise closing.

The problems with recommending a different site is 1. you are probably wrong, and 2. the question is probably not of acceptable quality anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I should have used an "other"-flag then.