# Moving questions to new websites

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Should questions about software testing and quality assurance frameworks (like selenium) be moved to [sqa.stackexchange.com](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/) ?
A new website has been created in the network that is responsible for Quality Assurance of software.

*Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers.*

So should questions that were previously asked in SO but fall in the scope of the new site be moved there?

Comment: Without much more context I would say: No. Yes. Maybe.

Comment: Let me edit that

Comment: [What is the correct behaviour when I see a question that would be more appropriate for another site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288601/what-is-the-correct-behaviour-when-i-see-a-question-that-would-be-more-appropria)

Comment: Questions don't become off topic just because there might be a better site for them. If the questions you have in mind are on topic on Stack Overflow, then there's no reason to move them anywhere. Also, note that SQA is a beta site. There's no guarantee it will become a permanent fixture on the network.